# access an object previously filled by another html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 files html (index.html and event.html).

in my index.html in my file I import a JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/events/createEventOBJ.js"></script>
```

and this is my js example with filled object (infact, with console.log I can see my newObj):

```
var newObj = [];

function getOBJ(eventObj){
    newObj = eventObj;
    console.log(newObj);
}

function createObj(){
    return newObj;
}
```

now, in another html file (event.html, in which I entered with a button in the index.html file) I use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/events/createEventOBJ.js"></script>

  <script>
    console.log(createObj());
  </script>
```

but it is empty, why?

And, another question is:

if in event.html I have something like this:

```
<div id="idevent" class="classGraph"></div>
```

and in createEventObj.js I use this:

```
  var event1 = document.getElementById('idevent');
```

event1 is undefined, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Js variables (e.g. your created objects) between to html pages are independent. It means that they have different instances and you cant share object like that. If you are on index.html and you are going to another page every js variable from index.html are destroyed.

If you want to share between two pages some variables you need to use cookies or local storage or have backend to store the values.
Or you need SPA